# Angularjs spinner control using $q.all

Tags: angularjs, spinner, q

I am implementing a spinner functionality in my project. The gold is to show the spinner when one or multiple http requests are fired, and hide the spinner when the requests are successful. Because I don't know which request will be resolved first, I chose to use $q.all. I have a directive like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('spinner', function($q, $http) {
    return {
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.showSpinner = true;
        var self = this;
        self.promises = [];

        self.makeHeader = function() {
          self.promises.push($http.get('some/url'));
          // Code that builds header goes here.
        };

        self.makeFooter = function() {
          self.promises.push($http.get('other/url'));
          // Code that builds footer goes here.
        };

        self.makeHeader();
        self.makeFooter();

        // Initial page load
        $q.all(self.promises).then(function() {
          // Hide the spinner.
          $scope.showSpinner = false;
        });
      }   
    }
  });
```

The initial load works fine, but when user has an interaction which requires multiple calls to server, to rebuild the header and footer. How do I show the spinner again and hide it when the promises are resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the repeated calls into a function.
I also recommend to make the 2 functions to return promise instead of handling the $http promise inside to provide more flexibility.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('spinner', function($q, $http) {
    return {
      controller: function($scope) {
        var self = this;

        self.makeHeader = function() {
          return $http.get('some/url').then(function() {
            // Code that builds header goes here.
          });          
        };

        self.makeFooter = function() {
          return $http.get('other/url').then(function() {
            // Code that builds footer goes here.
          }); 
        };

        self.build = function() {
          $scope.showSpinner = true;
          self.promises = [];

          self.promises.push(self.makeHeader());
          self.promises.push(self.makeFooter());

          $q.all(self.promises).then(function() {
            // Hide the spinner.
            $scope.showSpinner = false;
          });
        }

        // initial run
        self.build();

        // subsequent call
        self.someClickHandler = function() {
          self.build();
        }

        // some other calls that need to use spinner
        self.other = function() {
          $scope.showSpinner = true;
          self.promises = [];

          self.promises.push(self.otherCall());

          $q.all(self.promises).then(function() {
            // Hide the spinner.
            $scope.showSpinner = false;
          });
        }
      }   
    }
  });
```

As you can see this approach would look better if you always call same set of functions every time, but what if you need to use spinner on other cases like self.other?

You can wrap the spinner in a function and pass it the promise array.

```
var showSpinner = function(promises) {
  $scope.showSpinner = true;

  $q.all(promises).then(function() {
    // Hide the spinner.
    $scope.showSpinner = false;
  });
}

self.build = function() {
  var promises = [];

  promises.push(self.makeHeader());
  promises.push(self.makeFooter());

  showSpinner(promises);
}

self.other = function() {
  var promises = [];       
  promises.push(self.otherCall());

  showSpinner(promises);
}
```

Looks cleaner?

Comment: Thank you. This is much cleaner.